# Why only second test suite print in extent report?

Tags: testng, appium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have generated extent report using multiple test suite.

But it only display last test suite in extent report.

here is my code

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {

        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(Utils.getReportDir() + "/report.html");
        htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(String.valueOf(new File("src/test/java/extentreports/extent-config.xml")));
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        extent.setSystemInfo("OS Name", System.getProperty("os.name"));
        extent.setSystemInfo("OS Version", System.getProperty("os.version"));
        extent.setSystemInfo("Java Version", System.getProperty("java.version"));
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));

        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);

    }

 @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test case FAILED due to below issues:", ExtentColor.RED));
            test.fail(result.getThrowable());
            String screenShotPath = MobileActions.Screenshot("Failed");

            try {
                test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        } else {
            test.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
            test.skip(result.getThrowable());
        }
    }



@AfterSuite
    public void flushReport() {
        extent.flush();
        loginAndroid.quitTest();
    }
```

to generate report i use below code with every test case.

```
test = extent.createTest("Add Image on Canvas");
```

and `testng.xml` as below.

```
 <suite-files>

        <suite-file path="Font_Module.xml"></suite-file>

        <suite-file path="Image_Module.xml"></suite-file>


    </suite-files>
```

it only display second suite result in extent report.

suggest me how to add all test suite result in extent report.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `@BeforeSuite` to `@BeforeTest` AND
`@AfterSuite` to `@AfterTest` and it should work fine.

Comment: I made that change and it's still same.

Comment: visit link to check project on git.
https://github.com/chetanJTH/ExtentReport4.0

Comment: it will be more helpful if you are able to upgrade to report V 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.helper;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;

    public class ExtentReportMain {
        public static ExtentReports extent;
        public static ExtentTest logger;
        @BeforeSuite
        public static void reportsetup(){
            
            GenerateReport();
        }
        public static String capture(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File Dest = new File("src/../BStackImages/" + System.currentTimeMillis()
            + ".png");
            String errflpath = Dest.getAbsolutePath();
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, Dest);
            return errflpath;
        }
        @AfterSuite
        public void wirteExtent(){
            extent.flush();
        }
        
        public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
            if(extent == null) {
                reportsetup();
            }   
            return extent;
        }
        
        public static void GenerateReport(){
            
            if(extent==null){
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH-mm-ss"); 
                String destDir = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                extent=new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ExtentReport/ExtentReports_"+destDir+"/Swarupreport.html");
                extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Swarup PC");
                extent.addSystemInfo("Environment ", "Extent Test");
                extent.addSystemInfo("Username","Swarup");
                extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\extent-config.xml"));
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please follow the above code I had same issue and that is resolved by  doing the following steps.

  Create a class ExtentReportMain this will be your base class where you need to keep extent object in this class,  please check the extent object is null or not by calling GenerateReport method. then extends this class in the other testclasses. dont forget to call getinstance method from the testclasses. it will solve your problem..

Comment: thanks for the help. I had resolved it long ago.

Comment: I also faced same issue then i appended date&time to the report name and now for each suite it generates different reports which solved my issue.                                       public static ExtentReports setupExtentReport() throws Exception {
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyy HH-mm-ss");
  Date date = new Date();
     String actualDate = format.format(date);
  
  String reportPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+
    "/Reports/ExecutionReport_"+actualDate+".html";
  
  ExtentSparkReporter sparkReport = new ExtentSparkReporter(reportPath);